# Navigation item bar button is not visible in navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

Navigation bar button item is not visible in navigation bar while using two reveal ViewController.
Home Tab View Controller is my first RevealViewController and Menu View Controller is "rear View" and I have custom segue from "rear View" to another Reveal View Controller from this Reveal ViewController connected to 
"front View" called Product List View Controller, in this view controller I have created back button but it is not visible in simulator as well device.[image]

Comment: For that you ll need to drag and drop "Navigation item". After that add your item on it

Comment: Have you check that navigation bar is not getting override by another navigation bar? means it's not showing another navigation controller's navigation bar if you are using multiple navigation controller.

Comment: Yeah I have checked navigation controller is not getting override and if I assume Second Reveal ViewController as initial View Controller then its working perfectly

Comment: Yeah I used Navigation item @iDeveloper